# Apache httpd auth fails with Bcrypt

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, bcrypt, .htpasswd

I'm using .htaccess and .htpasswd to authenticate users, but authentication fails every time for some reason. I have passwords in htpasswd hashed with Bcrypt (PHP's [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function).

Everything works perfect when using in production server (CentOS 7 with Apache), but it fails every time when I'm trying to authenticate in development server (MacOS Sierra 10.12 with Zend Server).

Do you have any idea what would cause the problem? Is there some configuration where the Bcrypt hash isn't turned on, or something?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the authentication type (e.g. basic), the appropriate `mod_auth_*` modules must be loaded. To see which modules are loaded in your Apache, try on the command line

```
apachectl -M
```

or maybe

```
apache2ctl -M
```

Compare the loaded modules from production and development server and adjust accordingly. To see just the authentication modules, try

```
apachectl -M | grep auth
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Following modules are loaded: `authn_file_module`, `authn_default_module`, `authz_host_module`, `authz_groupfile_module`, `authz_user_module`, `authz_deault_module` and `auth_basic_module`. Is there some missing?

Comment: Are these modules loaded in both production and development? Since authentication works in production, it should be the reference.

Comment: There are more of those in production, but I think that the bcrypt should be included in mod_auth_basic, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, according to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html basic authentication includes bcrypt.